# Unit testing where a dependency has a static configuration method C#

Tags: .net, unit-testing, static, log4net

I have a class that inherits a simple logging interface. One of the implementations of this interface uses log4net.

Log4net has a static configuration method that is required to be called in you are using XML configuration. The line is:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Documentation usually states to put this in a global event, but I want to keep all log4net code encapsulated into this one class. So I simply used static variables to track if log4net has been configured, and if it hasn't I call this method:

```
//This is static as I only ever want one instance
private static log4net.ILog _logger;
private static bool _isConfigured;

public Log4NetLogger() {
    if(!_isConfigured) {
        //This is needed to initialise the Log4Net logger
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        _isConfigured = true;
        _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(_defaultLogger);
    }
}
```

The problem is I have no idea how to test this. I'd like to be able to test that the Configure() method is only ever called once. The static variables and the static method combined with the logic being part of the constructor makes this tricky.

It feels like it's my code that's poor, is there a way that I can write this code so that the configuration call is only ever called once, and then, how do I test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use a C# "[Static Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)" to achieve your objective.

```
//This is static as I only ever want one instance
private static log4net.ILog _logger;

static Log4NetLogger() {
    //This is needed to initialise the Log4Net logger
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(_defaultLogger);
}
```

Since, by the spec, it runs at most once (per App Domain), you shouldn't need to test it. You would have to, however, handle exceptions more carefully since errors in static constructors are harder to understand.